# JFileChooser and .txt file parsing problems

Tags: java, regex, string, file-io, jfilechooser

I'm having trouble resolving a CCE. This assignment calls for
the user to open a .txt file at runtime and then have the compiler
do background parsing on particular regexes to determine if they
match or don't match (e.g., ACC or REJ), but the catch is that
the user MUST open the file with a JFileChooser. I've done much reading and 
research before posting this and the problem seems to be that 
JFileChooser, which as I understand uses java.io.File itself, seems
to only allow Scanner to parse input of a .txt file in this scenario.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/class-use/File.html

So, when I used solely Scanner to read all the lines of text in the file 
it 'compiled' but all the console output showed was, for example, "null 
null null null null" (e.g., if there were five lines of text in the file).
For convenience, the following is an example of .txt file that would be considered
acceptable (or ACC, for shorthand): **EDIT** this example should have each of the rules printed on a separate line

S:AB
A:0A
A:e
B:1B
B:e

I have provided my source code. Note that charSequences are just the viable 
regexes the Scanner/BR has to parse. Also, if any given line is rejecting (REJ,
for shorthand), we need to to alert the user then terminate immediately.Apparently 
I don't understand these classes as well as I thought I did...maybe I need to 
use something like FileReader and I'm way off base to start with but I'm just 
extremely frustrated with the complication of java IO in general. It's just so discouraging
because I put all this work and effort in and rarely have anything to show for it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Simplified 
{


public Simplified() throws Exception
{   
    readLines();
}

public void readLines() throws Exception
{

    //MUST prompt user to use JFileChooser
    JFileChooser ranFi = new JFileChooser();
    //approve condition
    if(ranFi.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        //get selected file 
        Comparable<File> file = ranFi.getSelectedFile();
        //create a bufferedReader for the file 
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((Reader) file);
        BufferedReader br = null;

        //create local String object the refer to file's current line 
        String currentLine;

        /**************************
         * Length(LHS,RHS) = 1,1
         * --CharSequence compilations
         * ******************************
         */
        //ACC
        CharSequence fp100 = "[S][:][A-Ze0-1]";
        //ACC iff is NOT the very first line of text file 
        CharSequence fp101 = "[A-Z&&[^S]][:][A-Ze0-1]";


        /**************************
         * Length(LHS,RHS) = 1,2
         * --CharSequence compilations
         * ******************************
         */
        //ACC 
        CharSequence fp200 = "[S][:][A-Z0-1][A-Z0-1]";
        //ACC iff is NOT the very first line of text file 
        CharSequence fp201 = "[A-Z&&[^S]][:][A-Z0-1][A-Z0-1]";

        /**************************
         * Length(LHS,RHS) = 1,3 
         * --CharSequence compilations
         * ******************************
         */
        //ACC 
        CharSequence fp300 = "[S][:][A-Z0-1][A-Z0-1][A-Z0-1]";
        //ACC iff is NOT the very first line of text file 
        CharSequence fp301 = "[A-Z&&[^S]][:][A-Z0-1][A-Z0-1][A-Z0-1]";

        /**
         * Length(LHS,RHS) = 1,4 
         * --CharSequence compilations
         * ******************************
         */

        //REJ
        CharSequence fp400 = "[.][.][.][.][.][.]";


        //create a Scanner for the file 
        Scanner text = new Scanner((Readable) file);

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader((Reader) file);
            //while there are still lines to be read in the file 
            //where currentLine = present line of the bufferedReader
            while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {

                //while the scanner still has lines to read in the file 
                while(text.hasNext())
                {


                //to remove trailing whitespace in the file, starting
                //@ the first line in the text file...
                String trimStartLine = currentLine.trim();

                //ALL feasible ACC permutations for starting line 
                if(trimStartLine.contains(fp100)||trimStartLine.contains(fp200)||trimStartLine.contains(fp300))
                {
                    System.out.println("first line valid...");


                }
                //ALL feasible REJ permutations for starting line
                else if(!trimStartLine.contains(fp100)||!trimStartLine.contains(fp200)||!trimStartLine.contains(fp300))
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid first line..." +
                            "...terminating");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                //once again removing trailing whitespace in the file,
                //this time trimming the whitespace in the second line
                //of the file, provided that iff the first line of the
                //file was valid to begin with...
                String trim2ndLine = currentLine.trim();

                //permutations have now increased to 6 since "[S]" isn't
                //technically required for ANY line other than the first line 
                if(trim2ndLine.contains(fp100)||trim2ndLine.contains(fp101)||trim2ndLine.contains(fp200)||
                        trim2ndLine.contains(fp201)||trim2ndLine.contains(fp300)||trim2ndLine.contains(fp301))
                {
                    System.out.println("2nd line valid...");

                    //only included two line checks for now...
                    //as of now if the first two lines are valid
                    //then print out the remaining lines in the
                    //file...
                    System.out.println(text.nextLine());

                }
                else if(!trim2ndLine.contains(fp100)||!trim2ndLine.contains(fp101)||!trim2ndLine.contains(fp200)||
                        !trim2ndLine.contains(fp201)||!trim2ndLine.contains(fp300)||!trim2ndLine.contains(fp301))
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid 2nd line..." +
                            "...terminating");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("no file was selected");
                }

            }//end of inner while
            }//end of outer while 
        }//end of try
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }   
                finally
                {   
                    try
                    {   //close text while lines remain,
                        //valid or not...
                        if(br != null && text != null){
                            br.close();
                            text.close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }//end of finally 
        System.out.println("end of file successfully reached...");
    }//end of approve option
}//end of method 




public static void main(String[] args) throws    Exception
{
    Simplified mn = new Simplified();
    mn.readLines();
}//end of main

}//end of Simplified.java
```

Bottom line is that no matter the placement in the source code nor the type casting of my Scanner and BufferedReader objects, I'm always getting a CCE. Any help would be tremendous. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your stack trace here

Comment: @ Michael hello there. The stack trace reads as:Thread[main] (Suspended (exception ClassCastException)) Simplified.readLines() line:83 Simplified.<init>() line:21 Simplified.main(String[]) line: 179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile` returns a `File`, I don't know why you're trying to wrap it in a `Comparable<File>` for?? File itself implements `Comparable`.
2. `Scanner` will accept a `File` as input.  While I'm not experienced with the `Scanner` API, I don't think you need the `BufferedReader`, simply creating the `Scanner` with a `File` as it source should be enough to get you running.

He's a quick test you can try.

1. Create your self a simple text file with the contents you need to test.
2. Create a simple `Class` that has just a `public static void main(String args[]) {...}` method.

In the `main` method try something like...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path/to/text/file/text.txt"));
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

From there start adding in your parsing logic.